Workarounds for Microsoft Outlook Calendar "This calendar can't be shared"
I'm want to share my Outlook work calendar to my personal calendar (Google) so I can view overlaps and schedule more easily... but due to an IT constraint I am not allowed to do that:
"This calendar can't be shared with one or more of the people you added."
I discussed with the IT and they will not allow this to be enabled due to "cybersecurity" issues.
Is there any way to circumvent this... maybe via Power Automate or an Outlook addon or setting up a different server of sorts to share the calendar with a private link to my Google Calendar account?


Due to IT constraints and cybersecurity policies, directly sharing your Outlook work calendar with your Google Calendar might not be possible. However, there are a few workarounds you can consider:

Third-Party Tools: There are third-party tools like Zapier that can help you sync your Outlook calendar with your Google Calendar. These tools often provide more flexibility and can be easier to set up compared to creating a custom flow in Power Automate.
Publishing Your Calendar: Another method is to publish your Outlook calendar to the web and then subscribe to it in Google Calendar. This method is read-only, meaning you can view your Outlook calendar in Google Calendar but cannot make changes from Google Calendar.

Hope it helps.

Publishing calendar won't work  (just like sharing the calendar won't) due to the IT constraint. I'm trying out Zapier and it looks like it also requires permission from IT... need an option that side-steps IT. Maybe an Outlook VBA script that can be auto-run... or some external app that can read Outlook calendar and add to Google... even just the next two weeks would be fine.

If you have access to your work account on your personal device, it is advisable to add your personal google calendar to your work account or add your Gamil account to the Outlook directly. More information: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-calendars-into-outlook-8e8364e1-400e-4c0f-a573-fe76b5a2d379 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-gmail-account-to-outlook-for-windows-70191667-9c52-4581-990e-e30318c2c081#PickTab=Classic_Outlook

Yeah, both necessitate using Outlook instead of Google Calendar, including for widgets. Seems to be the only option currently.

Hope everything goes well.
